# Regex-based linkifying not working as expected

Tags: java, android, regex, word-boundary

I need to highlight the result of a searched hashtag in an Android app. Say my search term is "#fun".

Sample string: "#fun #funny #fun123 #funtimes #fun#hi"

Desired output: "**#fun** #funny #fun123 #funtimes **#fun**#hi"

I tried the following -

```
Pattern.compile(searchTerm + "\\b");
```

where searchTerm is "#fun".

Result: "**#fun** **#fun**ny #fun123 **#fun**times **#fun**#hi"

Shouldn't the word boundary stop the substring highlight in strings like "#funny"?

This is how I'm applying the regex:

```
private void addLinkToSpan(Spannable s, Link link) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchTerm + "\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mText);

        while (matcher.find()) {

            int start = matcher.start();

            if (start >= 0) {
                int end = start + link.getText().length();

                applyLink(link, new ClickableLinkSpan.Range(start, end), s);
            }
        }
    }

private void applyLink(final Link link, final ClickableLinkSpan.Range range, Spannable text) {
        ClickableLinkSpan linkSpan = new ClickableLinkSpan(link, range);
        text.setSpan(linkSpan, range.start, range.end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan(link.getTextStyle().ordinal());
        text.setSpan(styleSpan, range.start, range.end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your complete code please.

Comment: `\b` works correctly. https://regex101.com/r/3jYEoy/1

Comment: Use this instead and see if it works :
Pattern.compile(searchTerm + "[^\\d\\w]");

Comment: @Alikbar - Your regex is not quite right. It could match a whole lot of things

Comment: @vks, hey yes that's what I observed as well. It should match when it's the end of a word. Should I alter my regex to check for 'ends with non-character, non-digit'?

Comment: @Mallika - It should work as expected. Can you show us how you are using your Matcher?

Comment: @TheLostMind That is exactly what word boundary (\b) does. It matches any character other than alphanumeric ones.

Comment: @TheLostMind - Hey I've edited the question to show how the library applies the regex.

Comment: For the current input and expected output...the regex is fine...you should check ur java code

Comment: @Mallika - `while (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.start());
         System.out.println(matcher.end());
        }` is giving correct value. You can pass it to `range`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll have to modify the underlying code. You're right, the regex should work fine.

Comment: @Mallika check Pattern.compile(searchTerm + "[^\\d\\w]"); as well. If it didn't work you have code problems.

Comment: @Alikbar - Missed your earlier comment. `[^\\d\\w]` doesn't match zero length. for example for `"abc"`, `matches("abc\\b")` is not same as `matches("abc[^\\d\\w])"`

Comment: @TheLostMind - can you add an answer regarding matcher.end( ), I can accept it.

Comment: @Mallika - I think it won't help other people on SO. Glad to hear that it helped you :)

Comment: Sure, thanks though :)

Comment: @Mallika: I guess you fixed it as `while (matcher.find()) { applyLink(link, new ClickableLinkSpan.Range(matcher.start(), matcher.end()), s); }`, right? Please also add the link to the library you are using.

Comment: @TheLostMind: see [this Meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217136). I think you can post an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - *So, if a question can help one person, someone is willing to answer it, and it has no other impact on a site, it should be encouraged.* --> I see :P. Will try to do it from the next time around (or later today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `matcher.start()` and `matcher.end()` to the `ClickableLinkSpan.Range` method:

```
while (matcher.find()) { 
    applyLink(link, new ClickableLinkSpan.Range(matcher.start(), matcher.end()), s); 
}
```

The `matcher.start()` contains the exact index of the match value start position in the input string, and the `matcher.end()` holds the end index of the current match.